# How do I execute a command file to upgrade existing IIS 7 web applications during a web deploy?

Tags: iis-7, msdeploy

I want to deploy a couple of web apps but, when deploying to a server which has the existing web apps,  I need to upgrade the application pools for those two web apps (to use ASP.NET 4.0).

I have an automated deployment configured via VS 2012 which works fine.  How can I modify that automated deployment (which uses web deploy to a Windows Server 2008 R2 server) so that it runs the two shell commands to change the application pools?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Visual Studio to create a package and then use `msdeploy.exe` (or the generated `.cmd` file) to execute the deployment, you can pass `preSync` parameter that calls a batch file via the `runCommand` provider.

If you're performing the actual deployment using Visual Studio, you're out of luck, since the Web Publishing Pipeline (the MSBuild layer that sits on MSDeploy) doesn't support `preSync/postSync`

Either way, keep in mind that modifying an app pool will require that your deployment user is an admin on the remote machine.